# A picture geometry problem

Tags: euclidean-geometry

[image: Problem geometry]

***My approach:***
I know only one way to relate inradius and sides of a triangle which is $\text{Area of triangle = (inradius)(semi-perimeter)}$

[image: sol1]
[image: sol2]

I am trying to get $RS$ and altitude of $\Delta AMB$ in terms of $r$ which equals to $b$ and $a/2 \; $ resp.
Tell me if there's better way of doing this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For convenience, define $p = a/2$ and $q = b/2$.  Furthermore, let $MS = h$.  Then $$|\triangle MBS| = hp = r\left(p + \sqrt{p^2 + h^2}\right),$$ hence
$$h = \frac{2p^2 r}{p^2 - r^2}, \tag{1}$$
and
$$MB = \sqrt{p^2 + h^2} = \frac{p(p^2 + r^2)}{p^2 - r^2}. \tag{2}$$
Similarly, by substituting $3r$ for $r$,
$$b - h = MR = \frac{2p^2 (3r)}{p^2 - (3r)^2}, \quad MA = \frac{p(p^2 + (3r)^2)}{p^2 - (3r)^2}. \tag{3}$$
Hence
$$|\triangle AMB| = pq = (2r)\frac{MA + MB + MR + MS}{2} = \frac{2pr(p^2 - 3r^2)}{(p-3r)(p-r)}. \tag{4}$$
Again letting $q = (MR + MS)/2$, we obtain
$$pr(p^2 - 3r^2)(p^2 - 4pr - 3r^2) = 0, \tag{5}$$
and discarding obvious extraneous roots, we have
$$p = r \sqrt{3}, \quad p = r(2 + \sqrt{7}). \tag{6}$$
But we can also eliminate $p = r \sqrt{3}$ since this would give $|\triangle AMB| = 0$ in $(4)$.  The rest is straightforward and left as an exercise; we obtain
$$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{p}{q} = \frac{3}{4}.$$

Answer (score 0):

This is an elaborated solution given by @heropup

[image: pic 1]
[image: pic 2]
[image: pic 3]
[image: pic 4]